# Trans-conductance amplifier using CS MOS amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, transconductance

What is the meaning of the text "Less control on input Impedance"?
Why did we add CS amplifier for this purpose? [image]

Comment: Hi! It's a bit hard to figure out what the author meant without some more context. It might mean that anything you do at the output doesn't affect \$V_{in}\$, but I can't say for sure without more information.

Comment: The obvious effect on input impedance in the first circuit is Miller capacitance. You might want to do some reading on that and how the second circuit helps isolate the input from it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond can you please provide any useful link for this reference content? Also, for providing isolation, do you mean buffer?